# mergetool is not opening in Xcode 8.0

Tags: git, xcode8, mergetool

First I pull the remote code after that I am identified the conflicts in that process, and then in order to resolve them I typed the following command.. in terminal window as like

```
git mergetool
```

But, it will not open merge tool.
please give anybody solution to it.. Thanks a lot to smart ones..

Comment: Any body, please give solution